# iOS UIWebView ignores css inline style

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I have problem with my UIWebView which is simply ignoring my styling. It doesn't style anything, everything seems to have its default looks.

Any ideas about this one? Below you can find the code and genereted HTML.

Here's my code to load and present the html:

```
NSStringEncoding encoding;
NSString* content;
NSString* path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"style" ofType:@"css"];
if(path) {
    content = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path  usedEncoding:&encoding  error:NULL];
}

UIFont *systemFont = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0f];

NSMutableString *html = [NSMutableString stringWithString: @"<!DOCTYPE html>\n"
                         "<html xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\">\n"
                         "<head>\n"
                         "<meta charset=\"utf-8\">\n"
                         "<title>Application</title>\n"
                         "<style type=\"text/css\">\n"];
if (content) {
    NSLog(@" content of css file is %@",[content stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"%FONT%" withString:[systemFont familyName]]);
} else {
    content = @"Could not load content";
}
[html appendString:[content stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"%FONT%" withString:[systemFont familyName]]];
[html appendString:@"</style>\n"
                    "</head>\n"
                    "<body class=\"main\">\n"];
content = nil;
path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:self.contentResource ofType:@"html"];
if(path) {
    content = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path  usedEncoding:&encoding  error:NULL];
} else {
    NSLog(@"Couldn't find content resource: %@", self.contentResource);
}

if (content) {
    NSLog(@" content of file is %@",content);
} else {
    content = @"Could not load content";
}
NSLog(@" webview of this is %@",self.webView);

//continue building the string
[html appendString:content];
[html appendString:@"</body></html>"];

NSLog(@"Full html: %@", html);

//make the background transparent
[self.webView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

//pass the string to the webview
[self.webView loadHTMLString:content baseURL:nil];
```

That's the HTML that is generated and dumped (see `"Full html: %@"`) before presented by UIWebView. If i paste it into an HTML-Document and view it in the browser everything looks normal, as it should.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Application</title>
<style type="text/css">
body,
*,
.main {
    font-family: .Helvetica Neue Interface, '.Helvetica Neue Interface';
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #FF0000;
}

.heading {
    color: #FF9900;
}

a,
a:hover,
a:focus,
a:active,
a:visited {
    color: #428bca;
}</style>
</head>
<body class="main">
<p>Some text that doesn't get styled</p>
</body></html>
```

EDIT: Here are the 2 files loaded, its equal to the log output of the `content of (css) file is` log statements.

style.css

```
body,
*,
.main {
    font-family: %FONT%, '%FONT%';
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #FF0000;
}

.heading {
    color: #FF9900;
}

a,
a:hover,
a:focus,
a:active,
a:visited {
    color: #428bca;
}
```

contentResource.html

```
<h4>Info</h4>
<p>Test test test test test test test test test <a href="#ermergency">ermergency</a>.</p>
<p>Still some testing with this</p>
```

Comment: tried it works fine in a web view (using the given html and code)

Comment: show the NSLog(@"%@", content);

Comment: Which setup did you test on? This is exactly my code, no modifications done. Pasted the contents of the files.